# Getting lat/long from locationManager:didUpdateLocations using CoreLocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I've looked at similar questions and examples but I can't seem to get the latitude and longitude from CoreLocation, as it says it is 0/0 if I look at the location directly in viewDidLoad. I have a breakpoint in the delegate method to access location, but I don't ever hit it. I am conforming to the CLLocationmanagerDelegate as well.

Code (ViewController.m):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
    _locationManager.distanceFilter = kOneMile; //custom defined this one
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

//Actual update of the location
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

    //Not sure if this is the best way to grab it?
    CLLocation *location = [locations objectAtIndex:0];

    //Breakpoint shows this as zero here
    [Utilities GetCityAndState:location.coordinate.latitude andLong:location.coordinate.longitude];
}
```

In my Utilities class

```
+(NSString *)GetCityAndState:(float)withlat andLong:(float)longitude{
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
NSString *urlString = @"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=";
//[urlString ] I am going to append the lat and lont to the urlString here 
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];
NSString *get = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Once I have that I am going to take the results from the reverse geocoding and return a string like LasAngelesCA
}
```

Comment: Edit your question to show what the code for your "`GetCityAndState`" method looks like.

Comment: And while we're on the subject, in Objective-C... objects and method names should always start with lower case letters (e.g. "`utilities`", "`getCityAndState: andLong:`").

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Edited. And yea I know, this is one of those personal projects where I have been lazy with conventions :-/

Comment: Is your delegate monitoring the request for authorization and for any errors that may be occurring with locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus: and locationManager:didFailWithError:?

Comment: Use this to access the location array, since the most up to date reading is at the end:     `Location *location = [locations lastObject];`

Comment: Yes to @KHansenSF and I tried lastObject with no luck. I'm not even hitting the breakpoint.

Comment: I don't understand.  You were but are no longer hitting your breakpoint?

Comment: @KHansenSF I was hitting the breakpoint when I had the method call directly in viewDidLoad and not the delegate method, I will edit my mistake on the wording.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33168/discussion-between-khansensf-and-j-man-morgan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm  not entirely sure why, but deleting the app in the simulator and rerunning it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the declaration to this:

```
+ (NSString *)getCityAndState:(CLLocationDegrees)withlat andLong:(CLLocationDegrees)longitude;
```

Instead of using "`floats`" for the parameters.